# Submitting Form Details to Mail via PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am fairly new to PHP. So, may be it is a very silly mistake I am doing. I have to send the form details to mail id. I browsed through The Internet and get the various link about the same. I got the files and changed them according to my needs. But I am facing error 500 and I am not able to understand what is the cause behind this.

My HTML is-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
        Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <title>app</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="form-messages" class="success">

        </div>

        <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" required> </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My mailer.php is

```
<?php

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "hello@example.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

My app.js file is

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        }).done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);

            // Clear the form.
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#message').val('');
        }).fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Can anyone please look into this issue. I have not much and I am not able to solve this issue. Please help me?

Comment: Have you configured the mail credentials in your php.ini file? or you should use swift mailer it is the easy mail sending function.

Comment: ya I configured the mail id]

Answer (score 0):

It is giving 500 error because you have code

```
http_response_code(500);
```

in else condition and which is getting called may be because php `mail()` functionality is not available on localhost (or on server which you are using).

Alternatively you can use any **SMTP class** to send emails. Also, You can configure your gmail id with SMTP class.

Answer (score -1):

may be you didn't set mail credentials see here how can you do this.
[php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php)